# How to select lines containing (only/at least) 3 commas?

Tags: notepad++

I have a text document which contains some lines with 2 commas and some lines with 3 commas.

I want to select all lines with 3 commas. How can I do that?

Here is an example document :

```
basb,asbdausd,asduasbd
sdauabs,asbudasud,busadasbu,asduasub
asdbua,asbudsdbu,ubasdub
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this works better than the other answer, as that one matched lines with 4 commas.

Of course this works with any character, just replace the commas...

If you don't want to match less than nor more than 3 commas per line, I used this pattern:

`^[^,\n]*((,[^,\n]*){3}$)`

Explanation of each part of this pattern follows (because regular expressions are NOT obvious to me :-) ):

```
^
```

At the start of reg expression, means from the beginning of the line

```
[^,\n]*
```

Matches any number of characters that are not newline or comma

```
(,[^,\n]*)
```

This matches a single comma followed by zero or more characters that are not comma or newline

```
{3}$
```

This means to find the previous pattern exactly three times before the end of the line

```
((,[^,\n]*){3}$)
```

Be sure to put parenthesis around this part to make it clear what repeats three times (not the very first zero or more characters that are not a comma or newline)

There may very well be a simpler way - but I've been testing and I'm pretty sure this works perfectly well in the current version of notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Notepad++'s Regular Expression](http://letconex.blogspot.ca/2013/06/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in.html) search.

For example, here's a RegEx that will match lines with at least 3 commas:

`.*,.*,.*,`

Which basically means find "Any number of characters followed by a comma, followed by any number of characters followed by a comma, followed by any number of characters, followed by a comma".

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and how to remove, say, the second one, if the line has at least 3 commas (I means I'm trying to find the pattern to fill in the Replace with field to achieve that)